# get Installer pkg from alias

Tags: macos, alias, dmg, pkg-file

I'm trying to install pkg from terminal in mac using `installer utility`. The pkg file is in dmg. When I mount dmg I can see only `alias` for pkg not original pkg though it is present as I can access that pkg through alias in GUI. This gives me interpretation that original pkg is hidden but I'm not sure about this. Is there any way I can get original pkg from alias?

Answer (score 0):

Inside dmg mount folder run command `ls -la`. This will provide details to which file alias is pointing. Yes it's that simple.